# WordPress sidebar alignment

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem .In post when i am allowing the comment box my page is rendering

properly but when i am removing it from that page the sidebar content is coming back to the

down side of the page .I tried with many css methods but couldn't fix that .

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the sidebar css style `"float: right;"`

Comment: but it will effect on all the pages